# Doctrine2 multiple join

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I have problem with my User Entity. I have code generated by Doctrine it is below:

```
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Frontend\UserBundle\Entity\SfGuardPermission", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sf_guard_user_permission",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    protected $permission;
```

Problem is with join because I can't join user and permission. What I must to do? I must join sf_guard_user with sf_guard_user_group with sf_guard_grop with sf_guard_group_permission with sf_guard_permission. Because I need to get User permission. I do not no how to write join like this in code above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBH thx for replay, of course you have right with everything what you have written. But my sf_guard_user_permisson is empty so I can't use it. I can generate this table, this is no problem, but then I will must maintain it. This is next work for me so i wrote code below:

```
 namespace Frontend\UserBundle\Entity;

 // ...

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     */
    protected $permissions;

    /**
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getPermissions()
    {
        $groups = $this->getSfGuardGroups();

        foreach ($groups as $group)
        {
            $groupPermisions = $group->getPermission();
            foreach ($groupPermisions as $groupPermision)
            {
                if (!in_array($groupPermision, $this->permissions)) {
                    $this->permissions[] = $groupPermision;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->permissions;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $permissionName
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasPermission($permissionName)
    {
        $this->getPermissions();
        foreach ($this->permissions as $permission)
        {
            if($permission->getName() === $permissionName) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

// ..
```

What do you think about it? Your opinion is very important for me.

Edit:
Thx for SBH help, I have got answer for my question. I have hope it will help other people. If you do not understand something please look at SBH answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not write this join in one annotation. In fact you gone have three entity tables `sf_guard_user`, `sf_guard_group` and `sf_guard_permission` and two cross tables which you can write as you already started, `sf_guard_user_group` and `sf_guard_group_permission`.

But since it looks like you try to migrate some symfony 1.x stuff to symfony 2.x:
The `sf_guard_user_permisson` table in symfony 1.x is a cross table between users and permission, containing extraordinaire permission for a user which are not granted through the groups the user is in, so you are already done.

Comment: Thx for replay, I have added new answer please add your comment.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment your answer, so I'm gone write here: your approach looks good, nearly as done in the sf 1.x plugin. You should store the permissions with their name as key in the `$this->permissions` to prevent having the same permission multiple times if you are member of multiple groups. This will also speed up the `hasPermission()` function. And prevent collecting permissions in `getPermissions()` if `$this->permissions` is not empty.

Comment: I have edited my answer, thx very much for your help. I will mark my answer as a correct because I have put code example into it. But without your help I would not done it.